# command line in su - and background

Tags: shell-script, command-line, scripting, su

I am writing a simple unix script to automate reading of a log file.
The following does not give any output to the terminal. It just asks for the password for buser and then it just hangs. I understand that this is because the commands in `-c` of `su` are executed in the background. But the  logfile had some logs and i wanted to output this to terminal. Is there any way to do this. Please note I dont have the option of using sudo command.

```
ssh -t auser@something.com "ssh -t aserver "su - buser -c "tail -f /logfile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is becoming a very common issue in these days, try it in this way:

```
ssh -t auser@something.com ssh -t aserver 'su - buser -c \"tail -f /logfile\"'
```

Comment: Hey @lese, You are awesome. This worked. Thank you. BTW how does this push the output to terminal?